# What’s the likely cause of ‘buzzing’ from this hi-fi speaker?

Tags: speakers, damage, buzzing

Something has happened to one of the drivers in my speaker and it’s now ‘buzzing’. (Our cleaners could have knocked the speaker over). There’s no obvious (to me) signs of damage having examined the driver after removing it.

If I place my fingers where the tape is and apply gentle pressure, the buzzing stops and sound quality seems restored. (Hence the tape which is helping, but not fully fixing the issue).

[image: driver showing where light pressure fixes the problem]

If I do the same 180° around the driver, the bass stops ( this is a bass driver)

The driver is a Kef SP1532.

Any suggestions before just buying another driver, as the ones on eBay all seem to cone without the centre tweeter.

Comment: Buzzing is usually a sign of the voice coil being out of alignment to the point where it's rubbing against the sides of the circular magnetic gap in which it travels. There isn't much margin for error. There also isn't much you can do about it. If the speaker was dropped, it's possible that the frame of the driver (which supports the weight of the magnet structure) got bent.

Comment: Try putting all the screws around the driver back in it could be loose and vibrating against the case

Comment: You can replace the foam rubber edge supports on the speaker.  There are videos on YouTube showing how to do.

Answer (score 1):

Nice work on the diagnostic.

The speaker frame is pretty stiff snd unlikely to bend unless you really crashed it with something that damaged the whole case.

That means either the cone deformed or there is something wrong with the foam around the cone.

The foam can age/crack or harden. This doesn't happen uniformly around the circumference sometimes and it pulls it out of alignment with the voice-coil.  And, sometimes heavier cones just cause the foam to sag over time and cause alignment issues.

One path forward is to gently cut the black (dark gray) foam from the metallic-looking cone in the center. And gently pull the foam away from the cardboard perimeter (remove speaker from cabinet first. Sometimes it is easier to separate foam from cone from the backside when the speaker is removed from cabinet.

Then measure the cone and buy a new one. There are many sellers offering cones on the internet on Amazon or eBay or specialty audio or possibly a
KEF dealer - I don't know which are "best" but most are "good enough".

Then look on YouTube for foam replacement videos.

Fine one or more that use the trick of playing a sub audible 50Hz tone throughout your receiver to help center the foam and cone. The assembly will be inaudible when it is centered. You'll hear your buzz if it is not centered.

It is a fun project. And about $30 to $40 for a pair of cones. If you don't like the way it turns out, buy a new one.

Comment: All good points: Also could be a magnet shard caught between voice coil and pole pieces. These little bits of course go where magnetic field is most intense, and where clearances are tiny, hidden deep inside requiring total disassembly.